# Invalid host error when accessing website from Domain instead of IP

Tags: nginx, digital-ocean, pm2, namecheap

#### Problem

I am able to access my website hosted on [Digital Ocean Droplet](https://www.digitalocean.com/products/droplets) from the **IP address** but not from the [namecheap](https://www.namecheap.com/) **Domain**.

When Opening Website using Domain:

[image]

Response when Opening Website using Domain:

[image]

#### Context

I have a react + node + postgresql project hosted on a [Digital Ocean Droplet](https://www.digitalocean.com/products/droplets) which is running two pm2 apps.

- appone is has a react frontend and node backend. This is running in development mode on port 3000 (using npm start command) not from build files from pm2.
- apptwo is simple index.js file running server on port 4000 from pm2.

```
database_admin@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-2gb-sfo3-01-marketing:~$ pm2 list
┌────┬───────────────────┬─────────────┬─────────┬─────────┬──────────┬────────┬──────┬───────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ id │ name              │ namespace   │ version │ mode    │ pid      │ uptime │ ↺    │status    │ cpu      │ mem      │ user     │ watching │
├────┼───────────────────┼─────────────┼─────────┼─────────┼──────────┼────────┼──────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ 0  │ appone            │ default     │ 0.39.5  │ fork    │ 1592     │ 76m    │ 0    │ online    │ 0%       │ 33.8mb   │ dat… │ disabled │
│ 1  │ apptwo            │ default     │ 0.4.0   │ fork    │ 2315     │ 74m    │ 0    │ online    │ 0%       │ 63.0mb   │ dat… │ disabled │
└────┴───────────────────┴─────────────┴─────────┴─────────┴──────────┴────────┴──────┴───────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

Note: below domain means my domain like abc-xyz.io

This is my nginx config file:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        # Add Domain Name here
        server_name www.domain.io domain.io;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
         }
}
```

I've followed the steps [here](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/10375/2208/how-do-i-link-a-domain-to-my-digitalocean-account/) to setup the namecheap configuration.
[image: namecheap]

And videos [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zOPH54ltGLQ) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=95BC1b5FVps) for setting it up on my Digital Ocean Domain for the Droplet.

Basically added two A type records one for domain.io and one for [www.domain.io](http://www.domain.io) both of which redirect to my IP.

I've added both my IP and Domain in CORS:

```
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: ['http://XX.XXX.XXX.XXX', "domain.io", "www.domain.io"],
    methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
    preflightContinue: false,
    credentials: true, 
  })
);
```

Let me know if any additional details are required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running the project in development mode as suggested, in development mode your application is server using [webpack-dev-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-dev-server).

While developing a React web app in local development mode, you may want to run the dev mode on mobile or quickly share the web app with another person via a public URL for your localhost (e.g. using ngrok or nginx). For security purposes, you cannot externally access your webpack-dev-server.

For production mode it's recommended to build the application as it'll serve files from static build, so you wont get any error.

Since `disableHostCheck` in `config.js` won't work. It's depreciated. Unless you are using webpack `version < 4.0.0`

Still if you want to continue with this, you can try various options to get things working.

1. As mentioned int the [Documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverallowedhosts) Of webpack you can edit the `webpack.config.js` located in `node_modules/react-scripts/config`

```
devServer: {
    allowedHosts: 'auto' | 'all' | Array[string]
}
```

here you can specify your host `allowedHosts: ['exampleHost.com'],`

2. Set the `DANGEROUSLY_DISABLE_HOST_CHECK` environment variable to `true` :

- Create a `.env` file in the root directory (where your `package.json` file is) of your project.
- Write this in your env file `DANGEROUSLY_DISABLE_HOST_CHECK=true`

> Not recommended, security issues.

3. Using Webpack-CLI
   `npx webpack serve --allowed-hosts exampleHost.com --allowed-hosts exampleHost2.com`

Comment: For now DANGEROUSLY_DISABLE_HOST_CHECK= true worked for me. I am going to deploy the build soon but just had the check if everything was working.